# XNA Trouble drawing part of 2D sprite sheet to screen, black lines result

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, sprite, sprite-sheet

I am currently trying to render a 2D sprite sheet using the code below and all it's resulting in is rendering just the background color of the image with black lines going through it. The image is saved as a .png file, using gimp.

I have tested with random sprite sheets downloaded off the net and they render just fine. Is there a way I might be saving my png file wrongly?

The frame size should be 27 x 27 which is the height of the actual image file, followed by how wide I wish the frame to be.

Here is the sheet I'm currently using:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace WindowsGame3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        //Texture2D holds the image
        Texture2D character;

        //Holds position of character on screen
        Vector2 Position = new Vector2(200, 200);

        //Frames current size (W, H)
        Point frameSize = new Point(27, 27);

        //Which frame we are currently on
        Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 1);

        //How many frames on a line, followed by how many lines
        Point sheetSize = new Point(13, 1);

        //Sprite animation speed
        float speed = 15;

        //
        KeyboardState currentState;
        KeyboardState theKeyboardState;
        KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;

        enum State
        {

            Walking,
            Punch,
            Jump,
            JumpForward,
            JumpBackgwards


        }

        //First state we have when character is walking
        State mCurrentState = State.Walking;

        //Adjusts frames draw speed
        TimeSpan nextFrameInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((float)1 / 16);

        //Changes each time we need to go to the next frame
        TimeSpan nextFrame;

        public Game1()
        {
            //Adjusts how fast things happen in XNA
            TargetElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);

            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here

            //Sprite sheet we are using
            character = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MainSprite");


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here


            spriteBatch.Begin();

            //Gives the name of the Texture2D variable, then the position.
            //By creating a rectangle, only what is inside will be drawn on the screen.
            spriteBatch.Draw(character, Position, new Rectangle(
                                frameSize.X * currentFrame.X,
                                frameSize.Y * currentFrame.Y,
                                frameSize.X,
                                frameSize.Y),
                                Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

            //frameSize.X * currentFrame.X gives current position of frame on X. Same with Y.
            //frameSize.X, frameSize.Y is the width and height of the current frame.

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rectangle is off.  The X/Y coords (for the 1st index) are 0/27; you need 0/0.

The black line is an artifact of the spritebatch because you are telling it to draw something that does not exists. There is no image at coords 0\27.

Take a look at `Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 1);`. You are assigning Y a value of 1, but you need ZERO. Zero based indices, remember that :)

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I knew it would be a simple solution and that I probably overlooked something. Draws perfectly now =D